# Delete the line contains specific words/phrases with PHP

Tags: php, text

I have a text file and I want to remove some lines that contain specific words

```
 <?php
// set source file name and path
$source = "problem.txt";

// read raw text as array
$raw = file($source) or die("Cannot read file");
```

now there's array from which I want to remove some lines and want to use them so on.

Comment: This question is missing its [mcve].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you have each line of your file in a row of an array, the [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function might interest you *(quoting)* :

```
array array_filter  ( array $input  [, callback $callback  ] )
```

> Iterates over each value in the input 
>   array passing them to the callback 
>   function. 
> If the  callback 
>   function returns true, the current
>   value from input  is returned into the
>   result array. Array keys are
>   preserved.

And you can use [`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos) or [`stripos`](http://php.net/stripos) to determine if a string is contained in another one.

For instance, let's suppose we have this array :

```
$arr = array(
  'this is a test',
  'glop test',
  'i like php',
  'a badword, glop is', 
);
```

We could define a callback function that would filter out lines containing "`glop`" :

```
function keep_no_glop($line) {
  if (strpos($line, 'glop') !== false) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

And use that function with `array_filter` :

```
$arr_filtered = array_filter($arr, 'keep_no_glop');
var_dump($arr_filtered);
```

And we'd get this kind of output :

```
array
  0 => string 'this is a test' (length=14)
  2 => string 'i like php' (length=10)
```

i.e. we have removed all the lines containing the "badword" "glop".

Of course, now that you have the basic idea, nothing prevents you from using a more complex callback function ;-)

---

**Edit after comments :** here's a full portion of code that should work :

First of all, you have your list of lines :

```
$arr = array(
  'this is a test',
  'glop test',
  'i like php',
  'a badword, glop is', 
);
```

Then, you load the list of bad words from a file :

And you trim each line, and remove empty lines, to make sure you only end up with "words" in the `$bad_words` array, and not blank stuff that would cause troubles.

```
$bad_words = array_filter(array_map('trim', file('your_file_with_bad_words.txt')));
var_dump($bad_words);
```

The `$bad_words` array contains, from my test file :

```
array
  0 => string 'glop' (length=4)
  1 => string 'test' (length=4)
```

Then, the callback function, that loops over that array of bad words:

Note : using a global variable is not that nice :-( But the callback function called by `array_filter` doesn't get any other parameter, and I didn't want to load the file each time the callback function is called.

```
function keep_no_glop($line) {
  global $bad_words;
  foreach ($bad_words as $bad_word) {
      if (strpos($line, $bad_word) !== false) {
        return false;
      }
  }
  return true;
}
```

And, as before, you can use `array_filter` to filter the lines :

```
$arr_filtered = array_filter($arr, 'keep_no_glop');
var_dump($arr_filtered);
```

Which, this time, gives you :

```
array
  2 => string 'i like php' (length=10)
```

Comment: just tell me wat to do if i want to add a list of words, like if i can write a another list of words,one word per line then ? and if i want to add more words with glop

Comment: A solution would be to use `strpos` for each word or your "bad words" list ; i.e. using `foreach` to loop over the array, testing each word against the line, with `strpos` ;;; or if you want a more basic comparison, using `preg_match` could be OK too, using a regex such as `/word1|word2|word3/`

Comment: acctually i have changed my mind and now i want to make another text file contain bad words/lines at each line which shud be matched and removed accordingly any idea ?

Comment: The easier way would, then, be to load the file into an array, and use that array like I said in my previous comment *(i.e. the function that checks whether a line is OK or not doesn't need to know where the list of words comes from)* ;;; and you already know how to load a file into an array ;-)

Comment: lol i m not a programmer just trying my luck with some code :D , i m learning it quickly :D

Comment: Learning is great ;-) -- and we all started not knowing much about programming ^^ *(And happilly, we are still learning, even after a couple of years)*

Comment: now i m using 2nd answer plz just tell me how to load a file with that

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide a more complete example, that load the list of bad words from a file ; hope this helps.

Comment: wow it works and i learned to much today, books sucks sometimes and practical rocks :D

Comment: Practice (with trials and errors, of course) is the best way to learn, in my opinion :-)

Answer (score 3):

This will remove all *rows* that have a blacklisted word in it:

```
$rows = file("problem.txt");    
$blacklist = "foo|bar|lol";

foreach($rows as $key => $row) {
    if(preg_match("/($blacklist)/", $row)) {
        unset($rows[$key]);
    }
}

file_put_contents("solved.txt", implode("\n", $rows));
```

Or, if you are using PHP 5.3, you can use a lambda function with array_filter:

```
$rows = file("problem.txt");    
$blacklist = "foo|bar|lol";
$rows = array_filter($rows, function($row) {
    return preg_match("/($blacklist)/", $row);
});

file_put_contents("solved.txt", implode("\n", $rows));
```

Prior to PHP 5.3, a solution using `array_filter` would actually use up more rows than the first solution I posted, so I'll leave that out.

Comment: There is no benefit to wrapping the regex pattern in a capture group if you are capturing the entire full string match.

Answer (score 3):

```
$file=file("problem.txt");
$a = preg_grep("/martin|john/",$file,PREG_GREP_INVERT );
print_r($a);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [strpos](http://php.net/strpos) function.  It can tell you if a string contains another string or not (and where exactly the first string is in the second).  You would use it like this:

```
$good = array();
$bad_words = array('martin', 'methew');

// for every line in the file
foreach($raw as $line) {
  // check for each word we want to avoid
  foreach($bad_words as $word) {
    // if this line has a trigger word
    if(strpos($line, $word) !== false) {
      // skip it and start processing the next
      continue 2;
    }
  }

  // no triggers hit, line is clean
  $good[] = $line;
}
```

Now you would have a list of only clean lines in `$good`.

Comment: just tell me wat to do if i want to make a another badwords.txt file and use it with this solution, i tried but failed, acctually i dont want to open the code again n again :D thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

If you have a long string rather than a file and you want to remove all string lines that has specific words. You can use this:

```
$string="I have a long string\n
  That has good words inside.\n
   I love my string.\n
  //add some words here\n";
$rows = explode("\n",$string);
$unwanted = "tring|\/\/";
$cleanArray= preg_grep("/$unwanted/i",$rows,PREG_GREP_INVERT);
$cleanString=implode("\n",$cleanArray);
print_r ( $cleanString );
```

This removes that has lines contain "tring" and "//".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have an array of "bad words":

```
<?php
foreach ($raw as $key=>$line)
{
    foreach ($badwords as $w)
    {
        if ( strpos($line, $w) !== false )
            unset($raw[$key]);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$source = "problem.txt";
$raw = file_get_contents($source) or die("Cannot read file");
$wordlist = "martin|methew";
$raw = preg_replace("/($wordlist)/i", "", $raw);
file_put_contents($source, $raw);
?>
```

Comment: There is no benefit to wrapping the regex pattern in a capture group if you are capturing the entire full string match.