# Delete all lines that doesn't contain a specific word in php

Tags: php

i need some code which can delete/filter arrays which doesn't contain a specific word

or we can say keep only that contain a specific word and drop all other ones

which one use less resource ????

**update : the correct answer to my problem is**

```
<?php

$nomatch = preg_grep("/{$keyword}/i",$array,PREG_GREP_INVERT);

?>
```

Notice the PREG_GREP_INVERT.

That will result in an array ($nomatch) that contains all entries of $array where $keyword IS NOT found.

so you have to remove that invert and use it :)
$nomatch = preg_grep("/{$keyword}/i",$array);

now it will get only that lines which have that specific word

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267762/delete-the-line-contains-specific-words-phrases-with-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) with

```
$nomatch = preg_grep("/$WORD/i",$array,PREG_GREP_INVERT);
```

A more general solution is to use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with a custom filter

```
function inverseWordFilter($string)
{
    return !preg_match("/$WORD/i" , $string);
}


$newArray = array_filter  (  $inputArray, "inverseWordFilter" )
```

The /i at the end of the pattern means case insenstive, remove it to make it case sensitive

Comment: $nomatch = preg_grep("/$WORD/i",$array,PREG_GREP_INVERT);

dont know how bu this one removes the line that contain specific word, i need it to save that line and remove all other

Answer (score 1):

you can use [preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) with PREG_GREP_INVERT option

Answer (score 0):

Since this is such a simple problem, I'll give you pseudo-code instead of the actual code - to make sure you still have some fun with it:

```
Create a new string where you'll keep the result
Split the original text into an array of lines using explode()
Iterate over the lines:
- Check whether the current line contains your specific word (use substr_count())
-- If it does, skip over that line
-- If it does not, append the line to the result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$alines[0] = 'Line one';
$alines[1] = 'line with the word magic';
$alines[2] = 'last line';
$word = 'Magic';

for ($i=0;$i<count($alines);++$i)
{
    if (stripos($alines[$i],$word)!==false)
    {
        array_splice($alines,$i,1);
        $i--;
    }
}

var_dump($alines);
```