# PHP Remove line containing string from a text file

Tags: php, file

I have a file that looks something like this.

```
Kate
Johnny
Bill
Kermit
```

I want to be able to put, for example, "Bill" into a string, and remove "Bill", or whatever is in the variable, and the subsequent "\r\n" from the file. The variable will always contain something that is already in the file, there won't be "George" if there is no George.
This code checks if "Bill" is in file.

```
$fileContents = file_get_contents("names.txt");
if(strpos($fileContents, "Bill"))
{
    //Bill is here!
}
```

How would I expand upon this to remove "Bill\r\n"? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `strpos()` can return a `0` if the position is the first-character of the line, so your `if` statement fails. Try `if (strpos($fileContents, "Bill") !== false) {` instead.

Comment: Do you mean you want to delete the line of `Bill` ?

Comment: its a new line char whay u want to remove?

Comment: Yes, I would like to delete the line of <code>Bill</code>.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267762/delete-the-line-contains-specific-words-phrases-with-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$var = "Bill";
$input = "Kate
Johnny
Bill
Kermit";

$output = str_replace($var ."\r\n", "", $input ."\r\n");
```

Comment: If I just did `$output = str_replace($var ."\r\n", "", $input);` nothing seems to happen, but when I did `$output = str_replace($var ."\r\n", "", $input."\r\n");`, it left an empty line. I added `$newFile = substr($newFile, 0, -2); //Removes newline char` and now it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Ahh, good.  You could also do a trim() to remove any trailing and leading whitespace.  I appended an extra \r\n so it wouldn't fail to remove the last line.

Comment: I'll replace it with trim, just in case. It seems like a better option.

Answer (score 1):

- You can use `trim` to remove all white spaces
- `file` can read all the content as array
- You can use `array_map` to apply trim to all array content
- You can use `in_array` to check element of an array

Example

```
$fileContents = array_map("trim",file("hi.test"));
var_dump($fileContents);
```

Output

```
array
  0 => string 'Kate' (length=4)
  1 => string 'Johnny' (length=6)
  2 => string 'Bill' (length=4)
  3 => string 'Kermit' (length=6)
```

To check if Bill is there

```
if(in_array("Bill", $fileContents))
{
    //Bill is here 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(!feof($file)){
   $stringData = fgets($file);//read a line on every itration

if (strpos($stringData , "Bill") !== false) {
//do somting
}

}
```