# Delete that particular username from .txt file when browser of that user is closed

Tags: php

I am storing the users logging into a site in a .txt file .I want to delete their names when they close the browser directly.I am using php code.Is they a way to delete the name ?

Comment: How are you storing them? What have you tried? Stack is not going to create your website for you.

Comment: Please Provide your code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove information from mysql table when user close his Browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195581/remove-information-from-mysql-table-when-user-close-his-browser)

Comment: Short answer is : Don't do that. There's a better way to plan your application.

Answer (score 2):

There's no sure-fire way to tell if the user has closed his or her web browser. Trying to catch such an action w/ JavaScript will **undoubtedly** lead to bugs. The only thing you can do is delete said usernames after a pre-defined period of inactivity. If the user hasn't carried out any actions within the pre-defined timeframe, assume that they are inactive.

Comment: how do we know that he is not doing activity when the browser itself is closed?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the line of the text file in PHP:
[PHP Remove line containing string from a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719792/php-remove-line-containing-string-from-a-text-file)

To make a request on unload:
[JavaScript, browsers, window close - send an AJAX request or run a script on window closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162188/js-browsers-window-close-send-an-ajax-request-or-run-a-script-on-window-clos)

Answer (score 0):

As Wayne said, there's no *sure-fire* way, but one thing you could do is use JavaScript to check whether the user closed the tab, and then send an AJAX call to a PHP script that deletes the username from the file.

Comment: You can use `onbeforeunload` but very few things are allowed, and you certainly need to _finish fast_ or the browser will cut you off.

Comment: No, because it's likely not going to work and `onbeforeunload` is the wrong approach. What if the user has two open tabs and closes one?

Comment: @Frits van Campen He cannot open two browsers/tabs with same name.I use the same .txt file n check if already exists  before a person logs in.I have even this problem of not able to delete the user when he directly closes.